# Geolocation iphone simulator does not work (iOS/Titanium)

Tags: ios, ios8, geolocation

I am using Titanium to run location services, on my device it works fine, however when I run the iphone app on a iphone simulator I have to keep on manually turning on location services like this debug-> location -> Apple.

How do fix this

Comment: which iOS Version into you fetch this issue?

Comment: If you are working with iOS 8, have you tried to set the location to be tested with in the Scheme? You may do this in XCode via Product->Scheme->edit Scheme

Comment: Ranesh  I am using IoS 8